# Compact Set for Dummies

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization

Can any one tell me in simple words what is a compact set?
I read the definition of [Compact set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompactSet.html), but do not get it.
BTW, I do not know topology.

In particular, is the probability simplex,  $W\ge0, W1=1$, a compact set?

Comment: A set is compact if it is closed and bounded.

Comment: Closed and bounded, you mean.  But that's only true in locally compact spaces, e.g. ${\mathbb R}^n$.

Comment: @Charlie is right in most cases that you'll care about at the start. But if you don't know what "closed" is (it is a topological term) it will probably still need further explanation.

Comment: @RobertIsrael ,@ThomasAndrews Thanks a lot!

Comment: Compact sets are "small", the next step up from finite.

Comment: The problem with that intuition, @Neal, is that the subset of a compact set is not necessarily compact, which violates our intuition of "small."

Comment: And yes, the $n$-simplex, whether the probability simplex or any other definition of the same topology, is a compact space.

Comment: Closed and *totally* bounded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One useful characterization, especially as regards optimization: a set $S$ (in a metric space) is compact if and only if every continuous function on $S$ has a maximum.

Comment: Presumably, you mean continuous real-valued function...

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.